# Can't get jquery form input validation working

Tags: jquery

noob question...

Had the same kind of question yesterday. Managed to get it working without an answer. Today, same script, different divs -not working.

Html of it

```
<div class="imgform">
<form>
Login:
<input type="text" id="imglogin" name="login">
Password:
<input type="password" id="imgpass" name="pass">

<a class="imglogin" href="#">Login</a>
</form>
</div>
```

And the script it self

```
$(".imglogin").click(function(){

    var password = "111";
    if($("#imgpass").val() !== password) {
        $("#imgform").text("Incorrect password");
    } else {
        window.location.href = "http://google.com";
```

}
        });

Went over the script a few times. Can't figure out where is my mistake

Comment: What happens? What error do you get? Have you debugged with the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must load jquery in `<head>` block

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript">
```

HTML (added a div with id of imgform to display any answers)

```
<div class="imgform">
    <form>Login:
        <input type="text" id="imglogin" name="login">Password:
        <input type="password" id="imgpass" name="pass">
<a class="imglogin" href="#">Login</a>
            <div id="imgform"></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Try this

```
$(window).load(function(){
$(".imglogin").click(function () {
console.log('working')
    var password = "111";
    if ($("#imgpass").val() != password) {
        $("#imgform").text("Incorrect password"); //I added div with id imgform
    } else {
        window.location.href = "http://google.com";
    }
});
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pG99u/2/)

Comment: Change #imgform to .imgform.

Comment: @JayBlanchard see demo fiddle html i added new div

Comment: that wasn't apparent here. Add those changes so that the code is preserved with your answer.

Comment: @JayBlanchard thats a perfect way to show error text thats why OP accept this as answer

Comment: I know that it is, but the code may be lost if something goes wrong with jsfiddle. Please add the changes here so that SO can preserve the code for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.imgform` instead of `#imgform` when password wrong and another one is  missing curly brace `}`

#### Check this <kbd>**[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6tdm/)**</kbd>

#### jQuery

```
$(".imglogin").click(function(){

    var password = "111";
    if($("#imgpass").val() != password) {
        $(".imgform").text("Incorrect password");
    } else {
        window.location.href = "http://google.com";   
    }
});
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="imgform">
<form>
Login:
    <input type="text" id="imglogin" name="login" />
Password:
    <input type="password" id="imgpass" name="pass" />

<a class="imglogin" href="#">Login</a>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing curly brace for your if statement -

```
$(".imglogin").click(function(){

    var password = "111";
    if($("#imgpass").val() !== password) {
        $(".imgform").text("Incorrect password"); // using a class instead of an id here
    } else {
        window.location.href = "http://google.com";   
    } // right here
});
```